# oracle pl/sql pass exception type to function

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

i'm trying to find out if there is a way to get the type of exception without explicitly implementing all [predefined Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm#784) in a `when` clause.

I wrote a function to send a mail. I call this function in the `when others` clause of a PL/SQL Procedure, is there a way to pass the type as a varchar or something? 
It would be excelling to get the Exception message to pass as an argument too.

regards

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS848

Comment: thanks, tested it and worked fine. Please make an answer out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) suggested in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46190474/oracle-pl-sql-pass-exception-type-to-function/46211945#comment79343166_46190474), one can simply use the variables `SQLCODE` and `SQLERRM` to retrieve the Exception. It does not retrieve the type of Exception per se but it definitely provides enough information to solve the Problem. [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS848)

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Search in Oracle Documentation for : **DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK**

Answer (score 0):

there are several way , I use `SQLERRM`

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN CANNOTPROCEED THEN


      ORA_ERROR:=SQLERRM;

      ROLLBACK;
insert into LOG_TABLE (LOG_ERROR) Values();
commit;
```